Facebook live comments link has already not available?
I have used the link of "https://streaming-graph.facebook.com/%7Blive-video-id%7D/live_comments?access_token=%7Baccess-token%7D" to get live comments ,but the responce backs me 404 code and message is Response{protocol=h2, code=404, message=, url=https://m.facebook.com/melivevideoid/live_comments?access_token=metoken.
how can I solve the problem?
I just use the sample of facebook live comments ,and I am developing for Android Okhttp sse,so what can I do?
Sample code:
class SSEClient : EventSourceListener() {

    private val TAG = "LiveVideosEventSource"
    private var eventSource:EventSource? = null

    fun start(liveVideoId: String, targetToken: String) {
        val request = Request.Builder()
            .url("https://streaming-graph.facebook.com/$liveVideoId/live_comments?access_token=$targetToken")
            .header("Accept", "application/json")
            .addHeader("Accept", "text/event-stream")
            .build()
        val client = OkHttpClient
            .Builder()
            .callTimeout(2, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
            .readTimeout(2, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
            .build()
        eventSource = EventSources.createFactory(client).newEventSource(request,this)
    }

    fun stop() {
        Log.d(TAG, "stop: ")
        eventSource?.cancel()
        eventSource = null
    }

    override fun onOpen(eventSource: EventSource, response: Response) {
        super.onOpen(eventSource, response)
        Log.d(TAG, "onOpen: ")
        totalTime = 20
        toast("start live video comments")
    }

    override fun onEvent(eventSource: EventSource, id: String?, type: String?, data: String) {
        super.onEvent(eventSource, id, type, data)
        Log.d(TAG, "onEvent: $data")
    }

    override fun onClosed(eventSource: EventSource) {
        super.onClosed(eventSource)
        Log.d(TAG, "onClosed: ")
        totalTime = 20
        stop()
    }

    override fun onFailure(eventSource: EventSource, t: Throwable?, response: Response?) {
        super.onFailure(eventSource, t, response)
        Log.d(TAG, "onFailure: t $t  response $response")
    }
}


Have you verified that the video-id and the access-token are correct using some other tool like CURL, as they suggest in their documentation? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/live-video-api/interact-with-viewers/
